# Truncating characters in Advanced Custom Fields works some places but not others?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, limit, characters

I'm using the Advanced Custom Field plugin - although I'm not positive that is relevant.  Nonetheless, I can't get substr() to work at all using this method:

```
$givchars = 5; 
$postgiv = the_sub_field('get_involved_text'); 
$modgiv = substr($postgiv, 0, $givchars); 
echo ' ' .$modgiv. ' ';
```

However substr() does work when I do this:

```
$second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
   while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post();

   $titlechars = 5; // Character Limit
   $posttitle = get_the_title();
   $modtitle = substr($posttitle, 0, $titlechars);

   $attachment_id = get_field('image');
   $size = 'customfeatins'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
   $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ) . 'http://placehold.it/136x90';

    echo '<article>

        <img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() .'" width="136" height="90" />
        <h3>' . $modtitle .'</h3>
        <p class="date">' . get_the_date() .'</p>

    </article>
    ';

   endwhile;
endif;
```

I'm just learning WordPress and my php skills are pretty limited, am I totally overlooking something?

Comment: Ooops I pasted the wrong code there, that was something I found in another forum and it was all wrong... my bad! I have updated it.  Sorry...

Comment: What is 'it' in "it doesn't work"? `substr`?

Comment: yes, substr() - doesn't truncate the characters at all in the first example.  substr() does truncate the characters in the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like [`the_sub_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/the_sub_field/) echoes content. It is never returned for `substr` to work on. You need [`get_sub_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_sub_field/).

```
$givchars = 5; 
$postgiv = get_sub_field('get_involved_text'); 
$modgiv = substr($postgiv, 0, $givchars); 
echo ' ' .$modgiv. ' ';
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, that was it!  Thank you so much for your help with this, and for the links to the documentation on get_sub_field, I had completely missed that!